# How to format a number string to an appropriately localized display format?

Tags: javascript, format, locale

I have this code that calls an API:

```
<script>
  setInterval(function(){ getPrintCount(); }, 1500);

  function getPrintCount(){
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://data.memopresso.com/api/data/count',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'get',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
              document.getElementById("printCount").innerHTML = data.count;
          },
          error: function(data){
              document.getElementById("printCount").innerHTML = '0';
          }
      });
  }
```

I'd like to make it output numbers formatted like 9,55,100 (Indian format).

I've managed to find that

```
.toLocaleString('en-IN')
```

should solve my issue.

I try to put this into my code like this

```
document.getElementById("printCount").innerHTML = data.count.toLocaleString('en-IN');
```

but I can't make it work,
the numbers still display as a plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like in order to display the number using `toLocaleString`, the number must be a `Number`, not a `String`. It seems like your `data.count` is treated as a `String`. Try the following:

```
document.getElementById("printCount").innerHTML = parseInt(data.count).toLocaleString('en-IN');
```

Alternatively, if your number is a floating point number:

```
document.getElementById("printCount").innerHTML = parseFloat(data.count).toLocaleString('en-IN');
```

Comment: I use the second way, and it works!
THANK YOU so much!